# set STATUS field based on CREATED DATE field in CASE object

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying a scenario in case object.

Whenever a case is created with today's date the status of the case should be NEW.

On the next day, as the created date of the above would be yesterday date the status of case should get changed to ESCALATED.

If 5 days are passed, then status of case should be CLOSED.

I tried this with validation rule but it end up with "Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions."

So what is the other alternative to get the above anticipated behaviour in case object.

```
IF(  DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)   =  TODAY() , Status  =  "New" ,null)
```

FYR.. I am trying the above in VR.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the validation rules are for. And well, the case will be always created "today" ;) (at least in regular scenarios, sometimes you can influence the CreatedDate)

Read up about workflow rules (especially the "time-based workflows"), here's the [quick FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) and here are some [examples of workflow rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_examples.htm&language=en_US).

It's a "link only" answer but well, it's a pretty simple thing, you can also watch some training materials (either SF own's material or just search youtube for workflow examples)...